# How can one try to preserve his semen and make it raise to head (ojas)?

Tags: brahmacharya

Since semen is considered to be very precious, how to preserve it make it raise to head (ojas)?

Comment: Wet dreams and avoiding it is not a concept precise to Hinduism. You should remove it. Asking for Health advises is not under our scope.

Comment: Without help of Guru, the Kama shakti can't rise. For that you should develop some spiritual qualities before.

Comment: Vajroli Mudra https://medium.com/yoga-from-india/vajroli-mudra-231e4af1a255

Comment: Why do you want to raise your semen into your head, eww :/

Comment: I think this question has asked and could be a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The state where the semen's natural downward flow is blocked and it is made to travel up as *Ojas* is known as *Urdhareta*.

This is difficult to achieve but can be achieved through the practice of Yoga.

As, you may know, Yoga is eight-limbed:

> yamaniyamasanapranayamapratyaharadharanadhy anasamadhayo-a-shtava
>   anggani|
>
> Yama, Niyama, Asana, Pranayama, Pratya hara, Dharana, Dhyana, Samadhi,
>   are the limbs of Yoga.

And, under Yama, comes the following:

> ahinsasatyasteya**brahmacharya**parigraha yamah |
>
> Non-killing, truthfulness, non-stealing, **continence**, and
>   non-receiving, are called Yama.

Now, the result of Brahmacharya is stated to be Viryalabha or getting the state of Urdhreta.

> 38. बहचमपय णतषामां वीमरय ाब् ॥ ३८॥
>
> brahmacharyapratishthayam **viryalabhah**
>
> By the establishment of continence energy is gained.

All these verses are from Patanjali Yoga Sutras' Chapter 2 (Sadhana Pada).

So, basically the answer is that by following continence/Brahmacharya one can achieve the state where the sexual energy is not wasted but instead is converted into spiritual energy (Ojas).

And, Brahmachrya basically means to give up all forms of sexual conducts although it has a different definition for married persons.

UPDATE:

While it's very easy to say that, by maintaining Brahmachrya one can raise the sexual energy upwards, but that is difficult to achieve that practically and hence not much helpful as an advice.

So, let me also add to this answer few Yogic postures (Asanas) that help one to curb one's sexual desire and thus aids in Brahmacharya.

I have this book called " Yoga Sadhana and Yoga Chikitsa Rahasya by Swami Ramdev". From that book I have selected three Asanas/Mudras.

- 1. Aswini Mudra:

This is discussed in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29360/scripture-for-ashwini-mudra/29404#29404).

This Mudra is said to curb sexual desire and helps in attaining Urdhreta.

- 2.Brahmacharya Asana:

[image]

This is said to be extremely helpful in Brahmacharya (as the name itself suggests) and it also cures diseases like Swapnadosha (nightfall). Not that difficult to master this posture too IMO.

- 3. Go Raksha Asana:

[image]

The benefits of this Asana are the same as those of the previous Asana. But this is somewhat difficult to master compared to the other one (at least for me).

Comment: It's available in Bengali? Where did you buy it from?

Comment: Yes it's available in Bengali. I don't remember now where I bought it from. But it shd be easily available. Try any Patanjali store. @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: Patanjali stores usually sell medicines and food products...never seen them selling books...

Comment: Yes but they hv such books too.. You can at least ask them where to get this book form @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury