# Are there any prescribed Mantras, Stotras, techniques, etc that can help to inhibit sexual tendencies?

Tags: sex

I understand having Viveka about real and unreal is one way. But just wondering if there is anything mentioned in the scriptures specifically regarding lustful thoughts and tendencies?

Comment: Always think of Brahman, and if you are engaged regular worship of supreme, automatically all negatives are eroded!

Comment: @Akshay If sexual tendencies doesn't let one think of Brahman always, then what should one do?

Comment: Always remember this equation: Sex != Lust.

Comment: For Yogic techniques u can see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29653/4732

Comment: mainly avoid onion & garlic. lot easier to control food, which affects mind to incite sexual  desires

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is extremely tough if not impossible to control such thoughts on your own, instead pray to God, he being the inner controller will certainly help you.

Sri Ramakrishna The Great Master / [Sri Ramakrishna In Bhavamukha](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/sriramakrishna_thegreatmaster/srkgrtmaster_files/Sri%20Ramakrishna%20-%20The%20Great%20Master-36.html):

> A young man comes in a dejected mood and asks, “Sir, how can one be freed from lust? Passions and unhealthy emotions disturb the mind sometimes and make me restless in spite of me.
>
> Master: “**Ah, lust does not vanish till God is realized. So long as the body lasts, a little of it continues even after that realization**; but then it cannot raise its head, Do you think I myself am altogether free from it? At one time, I thought I had conquered lust. When I was sitting under the Panchavati such an onrush of lust came that it seemed to be beyond my power of control. I then wept rubbing my face against the dust on the ground and said to the Mother, ‘I have done a great wrong, Mother, I shall never again harbour the idea that I have conquered lust.’ It was then only that it vanished. Do you know, you people are now passing through a high tide of youth. This is why you cannot stop it. When a high tide comes does it heed an embankment? It then swells up, breaks the embankment and rushes forward. Then water stands as high as a bamboo over the paddy fields. But it is said that a mental sin is no sin in the Kaliyuga. Again even if an undesirable feeling happens to arise once or twice in the mind why should you feel worried because of it? It is natural to the body, it sometimes comes and goes; pay no more heed to it than to the bodily functions, the calls of nature. Do people feel worried because of such functions? **Similarly consider these feelings to be very trifling, unworthy of any attention and do not think of them any more. Moreover, pray to Him heartily, repeat continually the name of Hari and meditate on Him. Do not take notice whether they come or go. They will slowly come under control.**

Answer (score 0):

Perform sharanagathi to lord Vishnu do pranayama engage in social service always surround yourself with  people doing vedic sacrifice or guru who worships Vishnu specifically Madhava involve itself in Sangha activities importantly get Deeksha and chant Mantra thrice daily