# Who and how can one practise Brahmacharya?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, yoga, brahmacharya

So I've read so many books about Brahmacharya and most of them say that it has so many benefits but it is beneficial for only those who know to transfer that sexual energy into upper channels OR those who are already initiated and their Guru guides them with practical methods.

I've been trying to follow brahmacharya for 4 months now, but I have not seen even a single benefit.I'm not able to handle the sexual energy and my sexual urges are getting powerful day by day.Please can someone advise me on what should be my next course of action?

Comment: The following answer might be useful -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29653/4732

Comment: @Rickross from last 4 months I've been practicing siddhasana Almont everyday which is also one of the best asanas for bramhacharya but no benifit

Comment: In my answer two Asanas are mentioned ... Goraksha asana and Brahmacharya asana. Both of them will work. Not sure about Siddhaasana ... Also there is a mudra called Kamajayi mudra (search on Google for it)

Comment: @Rickross OK I'll try, about kamajayi it's a hasta mudra practiced only in right hand right

Comment: I don't know if it's to be done in the right hand or both hands (as usually done with most Mudras).

Comment: I'll recommend you read the book  **Practise of Brahmacharya** by Sri Swami Sivananda.It states many practical solutions for the problems faced by a sadhaka.You also didn't see any benefit(i think there many be some benefits to your body but just not enough to be visible) because merely practising physical brahmacharya is not sufficient, mental brahmacharya is also essential.

Comment: Also Brahmacharya!=Celibacy.Celibacy is a part of the practise of Brahmacharya.