# Is total rejuvenation possible after sexual intercourse and masturbation?

Tags: belief, sex, brahmacharya

It is well known in Hinduism that indulgence in sexual thought and activity reduces the highly potent energy of human beings called Ojas. I wanted to know is there any way to completely rejuvenate the Ojas we lost through sexual activity and increase the amount of Ojas from the previous time.

Comment: Only way to get back lost Ojas is by preserving semen

Comment: Yes I do it but after 4 or 5 days I again masturbate. So I just wanted to be sure how to increase the amount of Ojas after that. Do I lose everything that I gained or do I again a great amount of Ojas than that was lost? @Rickross

Comment: See this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29653

Comment: Lost energy can be regained quickly if one uses Ayurvedic supplements like Aswagandha but best is always to control the urge.

Comment: Thank you @Rickross. I always try to control but as I said , sometimes I do masturbate a lot. That is why I wanted to know.

Comment: Very few children learn to walk when they take their first step; most fall down and try again, but all learn to stand and walk and run. When you fail, don't think about the failure, standup and try again to walk again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind words @SwamiVishwananda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, provided you stop all sexual activity permanently.

> MAHIMA: "Sir, why does a man become deluded by worldly objects?"
>
> MASTER: "It is because he lives in their midst without having realized
> God. Man never succumbs to delusion after he has realized God. The
> moth no longer enjoys darkness if it has once seen the light.
>
> "To be able to realize God, one must practice absolute continence.
> Sages like Sukadeva are examples of an urdhareta. (A man of unbroken
> and complete continence.) Their chastity was absolutely unbroken.
> There is another class, who previously have had discharges of semen
> but who later on have controlled them. A man controlling the seminal
> fluid for twelve years develops a special power. He grows a new inner
> nerve called the nerve of memory. Through that nerve he remembers all,
> he understands all.
>
> "Loss of semen impairs the strength. But it does not injure one if one
> loses it in a dream. That semen one gets from food. What remains after
> nocturnal discharge is enough. But one must not know a woman.
>
> "The semen that remains after nocturnal discharge is very 'refined'.
> The Lahas kept jars of molasses in their house. Every jar had a hole
> in it. After a year they found that the molasses had crystallized like
> sugar candy. The unnecessary watery part had leaked out through the
> hole.
>
> "A sannyasi must absolutely renounce woman. You are already involved;
> but that doesn't matter.
>
> "A sannyasi must not look even at the picture of a woman. But this is
> too difficult for an ordinary man. Sa, re, ga, ma, pa, dha, ni are the
> seven notes of the scale. It is not possible to keep your voice on
> 'ni' a long time.
>
> "To lose semen is extremely harmful for a sannyasi. Therefore he must
> live so carefully that he will not have to see the form of a woman. He
> must keep himself away from a woman even if she is a devotee of God.
> It is injurious for him to look even at the picture of a woman. He
> will lose semen in a dream, if not in the waking state.
>
> "A sannyasi may have control over his senses, but to set an example to
> mankind he should not talk with women. He must not talk to one very
> long, even if she is a devotee of God.
>
> "Living as a sannyasi is like observing the ekadasi without drinking
> even a drop of water. There are two other ways of observing the day.
> You may eat fruit or take luchi and curry. With the luchi and curry
> you may also take slices of bread soaked in milk. (All laugh.)
>
> (Smiling) "Absolute fasting is not possible for you.
>
> "Once I saw Krishnakishore eating, luchi and curry on an ekadasi day.
> I said to Hriday, 'Hridu, I want to observe Krishnakishore's ekadasi!'
> (All laugh.) And so I did one day. I ate my fill. The next day I had
> to fast." (Laughter.)

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 20, Rules of Householders and Monks**

You have 2 choices if you can't stop masturbating. (Masturbation is also sexual activity as semen is lost.)

You get married and become a householder. Loss of semen is not bad in this case. Of course you will not have monk like ojas.

**Brahmacharya (celibacy) for householders**

> In their case, as prescribed, indulgence in sexual intercourse with
> their wives and abstention from it with other women mentally,
> physically and verbally should be understood as brahmacharya.

**Linga Purana I.8.18**

What Sri Ramakrishna is saying is for Sannyasis.

**Brahmacharya (celibacy) for monks**

> Not indulging in sexual intercourse, mentally, verbally or physically
> is the vow of celibacy, with reference to the ascetics and the
> religious students.

**Linga Purana I.8.16**

Loss of semen except during wet dreams is going to drain away ojas.

**Wet Dreams do not break Brahmacharya vow**

> One's vow of Brahmacharya is not broken by having wet dreams. In such
> cases the expiation laid down consists in the pouring of libations of
> clarified butter on the blazing fire.

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section XXXIV-XXXV**

Comment: I try not to indulge in sexual activities, but after like 10 to 15 days I masturbate, out of helplessness. Does this reduce my Ojas greatly? I just want a solution to retain the Ojas and become a celibate.

Comment: Yes, loss of semen due to masturbation leads to loss of ojas. You have to stop masturbation permanently if you want ojas.  Of course you will have to think of your objective. Do you want to be a monk? Brahmacharya for monks is different for Brahmacharya for householders (I have added 3 quotes in the post).