# How to practice brahmacharya as a student?

Tags: book-recommendation, brahmacharya

Recently I learned the benefits of brahmacharya . I am a college student and very much inspired by it. I want to know how can I as a male student undergo the practice of brahmacharya by following proper methods and strict self guidance. Also , I wanted know , that according to brahmacharya vows, a male student must not see or talk to any female person. How can I do this if I am in a college or school? Also I want to give an example- suppose I am reading in a college and there is one brilliant female student. As an aspiring student , I am copelled to learn from that female student, but this breaks my brahmacharya vow? How can I counter these, please give me the proper methods. Thank you.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29653

Comment: Use cold water and slowly fed by the penise when it is hard. This way you will not think more about sex.